# Strange thing about assigning value in ruby hash

Tags: ruby

The following two cases look similar, but the results are different. Interesting, maybe someone will make the mistake like this.

CASE1

```
class A
    def initialize
        @a = @b = @c = @d = @e = {}
        @e["e"] = "eeeeee"

        puts @a
        puts @b
        puts @c
        puts @d
        puts @e
    end
end
a = A.new
```

gives:

```
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
```

CASE 2

```
class B
    def initialize
        @a = @b = @c = @d = @e = {}
        @e = {"e" => "eeeeee"}

        puts @a
        puts @b
        puts @c
        puts @d
        puts @e
    end
end
b = B.new
```

gives:

```
{}
{}
{}
{}
{"e"=>"eeeeee"}
```

## Edit

The result is defferent between CASE 1 and CASE 3, but they assign the values in the same way.

CASE 3

```
class C
    def initialize
        @a = {}
        @b = {}
        @c = {}
        @d = {}
        @e = {}
        @e["e"] = "eeeee"

        puts @a
        puts @b
        puts @c
        puts @d
        puts @e
    end
end

c = C.new

#the result of case 3
{}
{}
{}
{}
{"e"=>"eeeee"}
```

Comment: Is this even a question? You're doing two very different things. What's strange?

Comment: I think people are being a little harsh here.  The difference is subtle and is because ruby copies hashes by reference and not by value, which is a concept that wouldn't be familiar to many novices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different behaviors are because ruby is not doing a full copy for assignment.

You can explore this in the console.  Try

```
a = {"foo" => "bar"}
b = a                  # b and a are references to the same hash object
a["foo"] = "baz"       # changes the underlying hash
b
```

You get `=> {"foo"=>"baz"}` because what you've done is create a hash object and bound `a` to that object, then bound `b` to the same object as `a` (i.e., they are both references to the same object).  So when you change `a`, you're changing the underlying object, and when you inspect `b` you see the same changes!  This is the same thing that happens when you do it as in your CASE 1 (`b = a = {"foo" => "bar"}`.

In your CASE 2, you're starting in the same manner by binding all 5 variables to the same hash object. But then you assign `@e` to a NEW hash.  It's as if you did this

```
b = a = {"foo" => "bar"}
b = {"foo" => "baz"}      # replacing b with a reference to a new hash object
```

In your CASE 3 you're binding all 5 variables to independent hash objects, so when you change one it is independent of the others, a la

```
a = {"foo" => "bar"}  
b = {"foo" => "bar"}  # b and a reference independent hash objects
b["foo"] = "baz"
```

See, for example, http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing "the same thing". `@e["e"] = "eeeeee"` sets the key `["e"]` in an existing hash which several variables point to. `@e = {"e" => "eeeeee"}` assigns a new hash to variable `@e`, which does not change the other variables.